# Maven - No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

Am using Wildfly 8 and I need to use the java batch processor from JSR 352. I downloaded the examples from https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples but can't get them to work.

On the batch folder I did `mvn clean package wildfly:deploy` but am getting the error

No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/krishnen/.m2/repository), codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/), central ([http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2%29%5d)

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You simply can add the following in your settings.xml file:

```xml
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.wildfly.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

After that you can use it like this:

```
mvn wildfly:deploy
```

Answer (score 6):

You need add this plugin to your `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And than call `mvn wildfly:deploy`, this should do the job :-)

Comment: Seems to have solved the issue but I get another error - 
Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY: /home/krishnen/Dropbox/javaee7-samples/batch/target/batch-samples.maven-project (No such file or directory)
Any ideas? U can reproduce it if you get the example on github. Thanks!