# wildfly-maven-plugin --> No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly'

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly

When I use `wildfly-maven-plugin` I get a strange behaviour. I think it is my mistake but I can not figure out what the problem is.
I defined a goal under the `wildfly-maven-plugin` so when I use `maven install` then everything is fine and the ear is going to deploy.
 I did not want to deploy the ear automatically so I removed the `executions` section and I used the `mvn wildfly:deploy` but I got an error. If I do not remove this section than the impact is same.

`[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]`

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
  <configuration>
    <filename>${project.name}-${parent.artifactId}-${version}.ear</filename>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>redeploy</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The -X command does not provides any useful info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405275/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-wildfly-in-the-current-project

Comment: I tried it, does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the FQN (Fully Qualified Name) of the maven goal.

```
mvn org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:deploy
```

Should very explicitly start the wildfly deploy goal and use the configuration you have specified.

The goal shortcuts only works in your configured pluginGroups in settings.xml, and as you can see it only checks 2 groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]

Comment: This will work, but the issue is likely the attempt to execute the goal in something like the parent pom where the plugin was not defined.